# uwp app using Mysql.data.rt.dll

Tags: mysql, win-universal-app

```
API CancelIo in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.RT.dll calls this API.
API CreateFileW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.RT.dll calls this API.
API MapViewOfFile in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.RT.dll calls this API.
API OpenFileMappingW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.RT.dll calls this API.
API PeekNamedPipe in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.RT.dll calls this API.
API WaitNamedPipeA in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.RT.dll calls this API.
API AcquireCredentialsHandleW in secur32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.RT.dll calls this API.
API CompleteAuthToken in secur32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.RT.dll calls this API.
API DeleteSecurityContext in secur32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.RT.dll calls this API.
API FreeCredentialsHandle in secur32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.RT.dll calls this API.
API InitializeSecurityContextW in secur32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.RT.dll calls this API.
API QueryContextAttributesW in secur32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.RT.dll calls this API.
```

Please help how to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WinRT (and also UWP) applications are supported starting from version connector/Net 6.7

If you have install from NuGet probably you have lower version. Use [direct link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html) to download and after installing you will find dll in folder like this:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.8\Assemblies\RT\

Comment: describe what windows 10 build do you have. add some more information. I want to reproduce this issue

Comment: I think the problem is using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps violates the Windows Store certification requirements. but i dont know how to fix it. I have to use the mysql.data.rt.dll

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The way I use to overcome was to comment the non-certificated APIs and compile connector again.

If you want to use my solution, or even better to improve it, feel to use and contribute in:

https://github.com/nudaca/MySql.Data.UWP